# Transform an array into object and set index for an unique key in javascript

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, array, functional-programming, ecmascript-6

I have a method that merges keys and indexes from an array into an object.

I'm stuck with ways to compress this method, and I don't know what I can do to make it simpler.

#### Goal

- get an array of objects with keys
- return an object with a unique key and the matching indexes

#### Code (simplified)

```js
const items = [
  {
    "key": 0
  },
  {
    "key": 2
  },
  {
    "key": 4
  },
  {
    "key": 4
  }
]

function mergeItems (items) {
  const helperObj = {}
  // loop over items
  items.forEach((item, itemIdx) => {
    const { key } = item
    // got key in helper obj? push index
    if (key in helperObj) {
      helperObj[key].push(itemIdx)
    } else {
      // create new array and set index
      helperObj[key] = [itemIdx]
    }
  });
  return helperObj
}

console.log(mergeItems(items));
```

#### Expected output:

```js
{
  "0": [0],
  "2": [1],
  "4": [2,3]
}
```

#### Question

Is there a way to do this without creating a helper object?

Comment: I wouldn't consider that an "helper object". You have a function that is supposed to return a (new) object. You have to create that object sometime, that can't be avoided. My "solution" would be rename the variable to what it is: `result`.

Comment: Thanks @RoToRa, You're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Is there a way to do this without creating a helper object?*

It may be possible. Perhaps what you are really asking is whether there is a way to have a [pure function](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/what-is-a-pure-function-in-javascript-acb887375dfe/), such that `helperObj` does not need to be declared outside the callback function and modified within the callback function before it is utilized after the `forEach` method is called. The callback functions passed to the `forEach` method typically end up not being pure for this reason.

Instead of using the `forEach()` method, the [`reduce()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) can be used. It still may have a `helperObj` for the [`accumulator` argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#parameters) but the scope is limited to within the callback function.

```js
const items = [{
    "key": 0
  },
  {
    "key": 2
  },
  {
    "key": 4
  },
  {
    "key": 4
  }
]
const mergedItems = items.reduce(function(helperObj, { key }, index) {
  if (helperObj[key]) {
    helperObj[key].push(index);
  } else {
    helperObj[key] = [index];
  }
  return helperObj;
}, {});
console.log('merged items: ', mergedItems);
```

Instead of either pushing or assigning to an array the array could be created when it does not exist:

```js
const items = [{
    "key": 0
  },
  {
    "key": 2
  },
  {
    "key": 4
  },
  {
    "key": 4
  }
]
const mergedItems = items.reduce(function(helperObj, { key }, index) {
  if (!helperObj[key]) {
    helperObj[key] = [];
  }
  helperObj[key].push(index);
  return helperObj;
}, {});
console.log('merged items: ', mergedItems);
```

And if the goal is to greatly simplify it, a ternary operator could be used to compress it even further:

```js
const items = [{
    "key": 0
  },
  {
    "key": 2
  },
  {
    "key": 4
  },
  {
    "key": 4
  }
]
const mergedItems = items.reduce((acc, { key }, index) => { acc[index] ? acc[index].push(key) : acc[index] = [key]; return acc}, {})
console.log('merged items: ', mergedItems);
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me think about this and I will come back later!